# How can I remove special characters from a piece of text in Python?

Tags: python

I need to create a list of strings from a piece of text, remove special characters (!,.?;:#$%^&*(),) from it and then to count how many times each word appeared in the text.

**Input:** 'operations, along with the additional methods described below.'

**Expected output:** ['operations', 'along', 'with', 'the', 'additional', 'methods', 'described', 'below']

I have a problem with removing special characters.

At first, I wrote this code:

```
original_list = input().lower().split()

new_list = []
for item in original_list:
       for i in item:
           if i in '!,.?;:#$%^&*(),':
               item = item.replace(i,'')
               new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

But it creates a list of only a few words which had those symbols.

For example, if the input is 'Strings implement all of the common sequence operations, along with the additional methods described below.', the output is ['operations', 'below'].

I also tried to add another condition (`if i NOT in '!,.?;:#$%^&*(),'`), but the final list contains the words without special symbols duplicated `x i`.

So, I don't know how to turn `original_list` into list with the same words in the same order but without special symbols.

Comment: You could help us to understand your problem by doing two things. 1) Post the (properly formatted) code you've written and 2) Show examples of input and expected output

Comment: A faster and better approach would be to replace the special characters before splitting. You wouldn't have to loop over each element that you just created by splitting.

Answer (score 2):

You could utilise the *sub()* functionality from the *re* module as follows:

```
import re

original_list = input().lower().split()

for i, e in enumerate(original_list):
    original_list[i] = re.sub(r"[!,.?;:#$%^&*(),]", "", e)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you very nearly got it, you just have an indentation issue, which can be resolved by moving `new_list.append(item)` out two levels. I have included all of the code here to demonstrate, which required very little correction.

```
in_var = 'Strings implement all of the common sequence '\
    'operations, along with the additional methods described below.'

original_list = in_var.lower().split()

new_list = []
for item in original_list:
    for i in item:
        if i in '!,.?;:#$%^&*()':
            item = item.replace(i,'')
    new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

This outputs the following, which I believe matches your expectations:

```
['strings', 'implement', 'all', 'of', 'the', 'common', 'sequence', 'operations', 'along', 'with', 'the', 'additional', 'methods', 'described', 'below']
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @cards Fixed - Good eye, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you could solve it with list comprension (most efficient ways to loop over a list). The str.maketrans('', '', special_chars) creates a translation table, and translate applies this table to remove the specified characters.

```
original_list = input().lower().split()
special_chars = '!,.?;:#$%^&*(),'
translation_table = str.maketrans('', '', special_chars)

new_list = [item.translate(translation_table) for item in original_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

String objects support *adhoc* functionalities for simultaneous replacements, the static method `maketrans` creates a table of the lookup values that should be passed to the `translate` method of the target string.

```
def remove_schars(string):
    map_special_chars = dict.fromkeys(list('!,.?;:#$%^&*()'), '')
    table = str.maketrans(map_special_chars)
    return string.translate(table)
```

Apply the above function to the input string and then `split` (different approach)

```
original_input = input("insert strings: ").lower()

# simultaneous replacements of the whole string
output = remove_schars(original_input).split()
print()
print(*output, sep='\n')
```